# heroku favicon mistake h 10 in heroku log

Tags: heroku, favicon

I deployed React app on Heroku.
My app is Your app was successfully deployed.
But when I go to the app URL  I see Application error 
I checked my logs I see these:

2020-06-07T19:53:14.194731+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=eco-maps.herokuapp.com request_id=a308ec6e-0c35-429b-a545-4b60ee7a6d9d fwd="5.102.217.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-07T19:53:14.702350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=eco-maps.herokuapp.com request_id=81b90ee4-1ef6-477a-9dc6-d5a14421d51e fwd="5.102.217.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I added favicon, but it doesn't help. Can you give me an advise?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the favicon. It can be for number of different reasons. You can read [this article](https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl).
On top of the fixes in this article there might be a problem with node buildpack heroku will use by default when deploying.